# Is there any benefit to leveling Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

As you continue using a certain Pokemon, it gains experience and eventually levels up.  What does this do?  Will it eventually evolve if leveled enough?

Comment: Pokémon can't evolve from leveling, but they will do more damage when used in battles.  Check out [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/208523/96435) for more info on how leveling works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The game says they "become stronger", and as you can see in the Pokemon menu (where you can set them as Support) for each Pokemon there's a *Power* value over its *Ability*. Pokemon with higher level deal higher damage.

For example:

- Level 1 Bulbasaur: 40 power
- Level 2 Bulbasaur: 43 power
- Level 3 Bulbasaur: 46 power
- Level 4 Bulbasaur: 48 power
- Level 5 Bulbasaur: 50 power

...and so on.

It's worth noting that the max level your Pokemon can reach is 10.

Usually the final Power of a Pokemon is the Base Power increased by 20. (Only 30 Base Power Pokemon have their final Power increased by 25)

**UPDATE for version 1.3**:

With the newly added **Raise Max Level** Enhancement, some Pokemon can now reach level 15. According to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/08rfcFxv), here's the complete BP/level chart:

[image]