# How do leveling and EXP work in Pokemon Shuffle?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

I'm playing *Pokemon Shuffle* and I need to grind my team a little more for harder levels.

So I'm now wondering about the leveling mechanics. They are quite vague, you can't tell how much experience a Pokemon gained during a match, if there are certain factors to how much they gain...

For example:
- Do my Pokemon receive EXP if they're just in my party or do they only get it from combos?
- Should I focus on higher levels or do they level up the same for no matter which level I choose?
- Are *Expert Stages* a good way to grind?

The only thing I know is that the Pokemon that's removed the most gets a crown icon with boosted EXP. But I don't know how much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/114531-pokemon-shuffle/71448207?page=1), Japanese forums are saying they cracked the EXP formula. Here's what they figured out:

> Each level gives *[Total Moves] EXP*. All EX Stages give 10 EXP,
>   regardless of the time limit.
>   Remaining Moves, Bonus Combo, Overkill
>   and Type Matchups have no effect.
>
> If you don't manage to defeat the Pokemon, you get:
>   *[Total Moves] *
>   [Percentage Damage Done]% EXP*.
>
> For example 64% damage on Ampharos
>   would get you 32 EXP (50*64%). **The crowned Pokemon in the results gets
>   a 2x multiplier, receiving double the EXP. The crowned Pokemon is the
>   one that's removed the most**, including those which are removed by a
>   Mega Evolved Pokemon's effects.
>
> The amount of EXP a Pokemon needs to level up depends on its starting
>   Attack Power:
>   Starting Attack 30 = 50 Base EXP.
>   Starting Attack 40 = 55 Base EXP.
>   Starting Attack 50 = 60 Base EXP.
>   Starting Attack 60 = 65 Base EXP.
>   Starting Attack 70 = 70 Base EXP.
>   Starting Attack 80 = 75 Base EXP.
>   Starting Attack 90 = 80 Base EXP.
>
> Other values are not checked yet.
>
> Each level is harder to reach than the last.
>   Lv.2: Base EXP * 1
>   Lv.3: Base EXP * 2 (total: 3x)
>   Lv.4: Base EXP * 3 (total: 6x)
>   Lv.5: Base EXP * 3 (total: 9x)
>   Lv.6: Base EXP * 9 (total: 18x)
>   Lv.7: Base EXP * 15 (total: 33x)
>   Lv.8: Base EXP * 18 (total: 51x)
>   Lv.9: Base EXP * 21 (total: 72x)
>   Lv.MAX: Base EXP * 24 (total: 96x)
>
> In other words, going from Lv.1 to Lv.5 takes as long as going from
>   Lv.5 to Lv.6.

---

**UPDATE for version 1.3**:

With the newly added **Raise Max Level** Enhancement, some Pokemon can now reach level 15.

According to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/08rfcFxv), the amount of EXP needed for those is:

> Lv.11: Base EXP * 27 (total: 123x)
>   Lv.12: Base EXP * 21 (total: 144x)
>   Lv.13: Base EXP * 30 (total: 174x)
>   Lv.14: Base EXP * 36 (total: 210x)
>   Lv.15: Base EXP * 42 (total: 252x)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning when the Pokemon is not defeated as this was my question.  Very good and detailed answer.