# Strategy for Catching Xerneas

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

I've beaten all the main stages up to this point (up to level 190 - Steelix at the time of this writing) and I still can't even complete EX18 - Xerneas, much less catch him.  I want to get Xerneas so I can get Yveltal so I can get Mewtwo.  Steelix was really hard for me to beat and I didn't catch him so I only have Mega Mawile, Nidoking, Nidoqueen, and Bronzong.

Is there some strategy I'm missing?  Should I just grind levels on this team until I can beat it or should I catch Steelix first?  Will I certainly need more gold or can I beat it without powerups if I get lucky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only strategy is to use Mega Mawile and quickly destroy the ice barriers in order to free the grid from disruptions. I suggest you not to waste any gold on Expert levels (although MegaStart could be useful).

**EDIT:** Home buffering was removed in a recent update.  You can no longer press the home button while playing a timed stage.

Your team is good, and I don't think you need to catch *Steelix*, its base power is the same as *Nidoking* and *Nidoqueen*.

If your team is at least at level 6 you should be able to beat it. It's kinda hard to catch it, I've always ended it with few seconds left, and I've caught it on my umpteenth try, with a incredible luck, at 1%.
Just don't give up.

Comment: I was able to beat it right at the buzzer using home buffering and levels 6-5-5-5 (Snorlax is a very effective method of training even if you don't beat him - see [this post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/208523/96435) for why).  Now I just gotta pray to RNGesus.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChaseSandmann I know, you linked an answer of mine :)